# wow.js is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have just tried to implement wow.js to my site but it wont work.
I have linked everything but i don't know why it isn't working.
I even added the wow.js and linked it to the html but there still seems to be nothing that is working. I also added the animate.css and still there is no effect.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"src="javascript.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="wow.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title> Vids </title>
    <a href="index.html"> <header>  <img src="images/Logo.png" >    </header></a>

    </head>



<body>

   <div class="vids-title">

       <p>Vids</p>

   </div>



   <div class="video-1 wow slideInRight">
       <h>Shia LaBeouf delivers the most intense motivational speech of all-time</h>
       <iframe width="550" height="435"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nuHfVn_cfHU">
</iframe>

   </div>


    <div class="video-2 wow slideInLeft">

        <h>Truth or Drink (Exes)</h>
        <iframe width="550" height="435"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pxYpvNMbdXQ">
</iframe>

    </div>

    <div class="video-3 wow slideInRight">

        <h>Walker broke his arm</h>
        <iframe width="550" height="435"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5-NXguyFFko">
</iframe>

    </div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function(){
new WOW().init(); 

});
```

Comment: Try linking it below your jQuery link

Comment: Nope that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Where is your JavaScript file in relation to your html file? Is it in the same folder or in a different folder?

Comment: all the files are all in the same folder

Comment: there isnt an error, its just not playing the animation when i scroll

Comment: is there anything in your console?

Comment: no there isn't anything in a my console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code - its working fine
https://jsfiddle.net/k3qaoyxe/
I included the directories as external resources and then

```
$(function(){
  new WOW().init(); 
});
```

worked fine.

Are you sure you have included all the libraries properly and they are loading correctly - check the network tab in your developer console.
Libraries included from cdn:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.3.0/animate.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.js

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"src="javascript.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="wow.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

should probably be

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="wow.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

You can also get rid of `language` and `type` attributes, they're useless and not W3C compliant.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked well after calling WOW at the window load event in addition to document ready event:

```
//At the document ready event
$(function(){
  new WOW().init(); 
});

//also at the window load event
$(window).on('load', function(){

     new WOW().init(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Animate CSS have been updated to v4.+ (Link-https://animate.style/)

Previously as shown in the **official wow.js documentation** (LINK - https://wowjs.uk/docs.html)

Outdated syntax to initialize wow animation :

```
<script>
    wow = new WOW(
        {
            animateClass: 'animate' // old default
        }
    )
    wow.init();
</script>
```

The new syntax is as follows :-

```
<script>
    wow = new WOW(
        {
            animateClass: 'animate__animated' //updated default animate 4.+
        }
    )
    wow.init();
</script>
```

Hence, you can't simply use this code anymore, it is not valid :

```
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new WOW().init();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have set overflow property to body,html or on parent container of wow box it will not work .remove overflow property from body or html