# How to animate a image with waypoint or wow with bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to animate an image with the fadeinleft animation, I want to use wow with bootstrap 4, but it does not work, i read that waypoint could help, please a little help here, this is my css and html code.

```
<html>

<body>
    <script src="http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/dist/wow.min.js"></script>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="wow fadeInLeftBig animated">
                <img id="img1" src="imagenes2/mision.png" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script>
    new WOW().init();
</script>

</html>
```

CSS3 CODE

```
element.style {
  visibility: visible;
  animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;
}

.fadeInLeftBig {
  animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wow.js is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855948/wow-js-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Look into **[WOW.js](https://wowjs.uk/docs.html)**. You could try adding the CSS [`animation`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.3.0/animate.css) library:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.3.0/animate.css">
```

I've put up a JSFiddle example here:

```js
new WOW().init();
```

```css
element.style {
  visibility: visible;
  animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;
}

.fadeInLeftBig {
  animation-name: fadeInLeftBig;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.wowBack {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wowWrap div {
  background: #27ae60;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5% 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.wowWrap {
  width: 16.66%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 .5%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Link to the CSS animation library -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.3.0/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Link and activate wow.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.js"></script>

<div class="wow fadeInLeftBig animated">
  <img id="img1 " src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-fluid ">
</div>

<main class="wowBack clearfix">
  <section class="wowWrap">
    <div class="wow fadeInLeftBig">fadeInLeftBig</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to link [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library and have it in ur css folder

*(You can link to another CSS animation library by changing wow.js settings)*

`link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css"`

you can check the [wowJS Documentation](https://wowjs.uk/docs.html) for further info